# What does "/" (forward slash) mean in this context?

Tags: logic, notation, modal-logic

I was reading *A New Introduction to Modal Logic*, written by G.E. Hughes and M.J. Cresswell, book on modal logic and the author uses the forward slash {/}:

[image]

but I was unable to understand it.

So I ask: what does */* mean in this situation?

Comment: Here, $(n)[E/v]$ means "the result of substituting expression $E$ for variable $v$ throughout the formula (n)". It binds loosely: $p\land q/p$ means, substitute $p\land q$ (not just $q$) for p. Two of your red circles should also include "$p\land$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From context, it seems like $(3)[p \land q / p]$ means "Take statement (3), but substitute $p \land q$ for $p$."

Comment: You are surely correct, because the says "we use the expression $\alpha[\beta/p_1, ..., \beta_n/p_n]$ to denote the wff which results from $\alpha$ by replacing $p_1, ..., p_n$ uniformly by $\beta, ..., \beta_n$ respectively." in a part before the part that I am in. I forgot. Thanks a lot for the answer!